# How to add S3SyncProgressListener when resumng TransferManager.resumeUpload(persistableUpload)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want Synchronization process on AWS S3 Bucket. I am using  [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)
to achieve this task. And I am successfully done resume and pause functionality initially by following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/pausing-and-resuming-transfers-using-transfer-manager/) tutorial. The problem now is when I am resuming upload then How can I add S3SyncProgressListener to support resuming uploads/downloads during JVM crashes.

```
// Initialize TransferManager.
        TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(awsCredentials);

        PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,deviceId+"/"+directory.getAbsolutePath(),directory);

    // Upload a file to Amazon S3.
    tx.upload(putRequest, new S3SyncProgressListener() {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        @Override
        public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) { 
            super.progressChanged(progressEvent);
            long MB = 1024 * 1024;
           System.out.println("Transferred Progress =="+ (progressEvent.getBytesTransferred()/MB));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPersistableTransfer(final PersistableTransfer persistableTransfer) { 
            System.out.println("TestCalled");
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        AppDirs appDirs = AppDirsFactory.getInstance();
                        String appDirPath = appDirs.getUserDataDir("OfficeBackUp", "1.0.0", "rayz");
                        File appDir = new File(appDirPath);

                        File f = new File(appDir,"resume-upload");
                        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                        if ( !f.exists() ) f.createNewFile();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        persistableTransfer.serialize(fos);
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AwsOprServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AwsOprServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(AwsOprServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And for resuming

```
   // Initialize TransferManager.
TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(awsCredentials);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(toResume);

// Deserialize PersistableUpload information from disk.
PersistableUpload persistableUpload = PersistableTransfer.deserializeFrom(fis);

// Call resumeUpload with PersistableUpload.
Upload upload = tx.resumeUpload(persistableUpload);

fis.close();
```

Now How can I add S3SyncProgressListener while resuming.